# Set combo box selected value from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a combo box and I am trying to set the selected value from the controller. How can I do that?

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedControl" ng-change="changeControl(selectedControl)" required>
    <md-option ng-repeat="control in controls" ng-value="control">{{control}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

I tried:

```
$scope.selectedControl = "Test";
```

Control array:

```
[{"ControlId":1,"ControlColumn":"Address","ControlText":"AddressTest"},{"ControlId":2,"ControlColumn":"City_State_Zip","ControlText":"CityTest"}]
```

Comment: Can you show us the `controls` array? By the way, surround `control` with `{}` like this: `{{control}}` that way you get the value of that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your options just pass the index of value`<md-option ng-repeat="control in controls" ng-value="control" ng-selected="index == 1">control</md-option>`

this will select the scond value in array so you can modify it accoding to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you. I am puling the data for the combo box from the database. And I want to select different value dynamically.

Comment: add index == selectedIndex and update selectedIndexvalue from controller according to your requirement.

Comment: Can I go by text value instead by index.

Comment: you can give a try

Answer (score 0):

problem lies in your data array as you need to select the value itself from the array to be selected in options, try to get proper array or split the data for better control over drop down selection.

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nq1eyj1v/349/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Type:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
         <select name="type" ng-model="selectedControl" ng-dropdown required ng-change="changeControl(selectedControl)" ng-options="control.ControlText for control in controls"> 
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {

   $scope.controls = [{ 'ControlId': 1, 'ControlColumn': 'Address', 'ControlText': 'AddressTest' }, { 'ControlId': 2, 'ControlColumn': 'City_State_Zip', 'ControlText': 'CityTest' }];
   $scope.selectedControl = $scope.controls[1]; // change the value from here
}
```